# Axis with wrong interval

Tags: highcharts

Please see picture and code below. Sample in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/KampfmeierDirk/ufjazwp9/1/

The ticks should start at the minimum 20185351 with the given interval 10101. The next tick should be at 20195452 and so on.

But the y-axis starts at 0 and the first tick to show is 20191899 ( = 1999 * 10101 ). Is it possible to shift the ticks in the desired way?

Thanks and kind regards, Dirk

[image: bar chart]

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 20185351,
        max: 20387371,
        tickInterval: 10101,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        reversedStacks: false,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                fontSize: '8px'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        data: [20185351]
    },{
        name: 'B',
        data: [100000]
    },{
        name: 'C',
        data: [10000]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tickPositioner` option:

```
yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 10101,
    reversedStacks: false,
    tickPositioner: function(){
        var positions = [];

        for (var i = 20185351; i <= 20387371; i+= 10101) {
            positions.push(i);
        }

        return positions;
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value}',
        style: {
            fontSize: '8px'
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h4rfju98/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!